# Specifying spatial coordinates in a data.frame

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, bubble-chart

Pretty silly but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

I have a `data.frame` with 2 columns:

```
df = data.frame(x = rep(1, 20), y = runif(20, 10,20))
```

I then want to set `x` and `y` as spatial coordinates so I can plot `df` in a `bubble plot`. So I try:

```
coordinates(df) = c("x","y")
```

But then:

```
bubble(df)
```

gives this error:

```
Error in data.frame(x@data, x@coords) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 20
```

Comment: you probably want to include a `library(sp)` in your example.  And perhaps a `set.seed(1)` as well  ;)

Comment: temporary workaround:   try adding a dummy column to `df` before calling the coordinates() function

Comment: Thanks a lot Ricardo. Sorry for not including library(sp) in my example and the dummy column did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For bubble plot to be meaningful, you should probably create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

```
library(sp)
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1, 20), y = runif(20, 10,20))
data <- data.frame(variable = runif(20))
coordinates(df) <- ~ x + y
out <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(df, data)
bubble(out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(sp)
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x = rep(1, 20), y = runif(20, 10, 20), dummy = rep(0, 20))
coordinates(df) = c("x","y")
bubble(df)
```

[image]

Comment: And the explanation? I suppose `bubble` expects a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` not just `SpatialPoints`?